# cloud-config does not seem to run scripts-per-once, runcmd or per-boot modules

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, cloud-init

The cloud-init.cfg below will not seem to run the scripts-per-once, runcmd or per-boot modules... it will however run the scripts-per-boot module.

Running cloud-init -d single -n scripts-per-once shows no errors in the log output.

```
users:
 - default

disable_root: 1
ssh_pwauth: 0

mount_default_fields: [~, ~, 'auto', 'defaults,nofail', '0', '2']
resize_rootfs_tmp: /dev
ssh_svcname: sshd
ssh_deletekeys: True
ssh_genkeytypes: [ 'rsa', 'ed25519' ]
syslog_fix_perms: ~

cloud_init_modules:
 - migrator
 - bootcmd
 - write-files
 - growpart
 - resizefs
 - set_hostname
 - update_hostname
 - users-groups
 - ssh

cloud_config_modules:
 - mounts
 - locale
 - package-update-upgrade-install
 - timezone
 - chef
 - runcmd
 - ssh-import-id

cloud_final_modules:
 - scripts-per-once
 - scripts-per-boot
 - scripts-per-instance
 - scripts-user
 - ssh-authkey-fingerprints
 - keys-to-console
 - final-message
 - power-state-change 

system_info:
  distro: ubuntu
  default_user:
    name: fred
     lock_passwd: true
     gecos: Fred The User
     groups: [users, adm, systemd-journal]
    shell: /bin/bash

  paths:
    cloud_dir: /var/lib/cloud
    templates_dir: /etc/cloud/templates
  ssh_svcname: sshd

bootcmd:
- "/bin/echo test >> /tmp/my_boot.txt"

runcmd:
- "/bin/echo sample >> /tmp/my_run.txt"

final_message: cloud-init finished 
# vim:syntax=yaml
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: How is this related to programming and especially Python?

Comment: Cloud-Init is written in python.

Comment: Every program is written in at least one programming language. But that alone does not make the program a Stack Overflow topic.

Comment: Everyone who knows a little python isn't a programmer either. Does not mean they can't be helpful and find a possible bug however.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: I've removed the python tag and kept the "cloud-init" tag as this tag should be obvious in the relation to the question.